# Unity - can build skip some parts of a script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I build my game it "skips" some parts of the scripts

In Start() of my Script some lines of code get "skipped" or "ignored" by build, but they work in editor.
There are also no if statements in Start() that stop some lines of code.

Comment: Yes. If you put them in an Editor folder they wont be compiled. Or if you put in s conditional compile directive and dont set it.   However start issues chances are its not ignored or skipped but silently erroring and/or running before things it wanted were ready.

Comment: Why would I want to not compile my scripts?

Comment: Almost always with issues like this there will be a simple cause. Building the exe will never skip any code so there has to be a logical problem. Post your code so we can help further.

Comment: I am not home now, but I think I found out what is the issue. Is it problem if I called a function in Start() and then created it after Start()?

Comment: To answer why you wouldn't want something compiled in? What if it's something for a pro version or paid not trial. Or what if its something youre working on but isnt ready yet. Or you need different behaviors for something such as ios vs android and it makes no sense to have 2 different copies of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED:
I just went to log file and fixed the errors there, and all worked. if you can't find log files just go:

Player Logs

Linux: ~/.config/unity3d/CompanyName/ProductName/Player.log

macOS: ~/Library/Logs/Company Name/ProductName/Player.log

Windows: C:\Users\username\AppData\LocalLow\CompanyName\ProductName\Player.log

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I can say the reason if you send more info. But for now, here are steps that you can take to find the issue and fix yourself:

**Conditional Compilation:** Avoid using preprocessor directives that change code behavior between the editor and build.

**Script Execution Order:** Confirm the correct script execution order in Unity settings.

**Resource Loading:** Verify asset references in the build, ensuring they're correct.

**Editor-Only Code:** Remove code enclosed in #if UNITY_EDITOR if not needed in the build.

**Dependencies:** Check for missing or misconfigured dependencies and libraries.

**Optimization Levels**: Experiment with script optimization levels.

**Debugging:** Add debug logs in your Start() method to trace the issue.

If issues persist, give more detailed information about your error.

Comment: Do you want me to post my Start() function?

Comment: post anything that can help to define your issue. codes, screenshots, etc...